# Check if string contain word in array and break to true php

Tags: php

I use code below to check if comment contains any word in array below. It returns true if detect word.

```
$blacklist = array("fuck","shit","pussy", "mail.ru","viagra pill", "bitcoin", "конце", "pharmacy", "bad credit","casinos");
function checkblacklist($commnetct) {
  foreach ($blacklist as $word) {
    if (strpos($commnetc, $word) !== FALSE) { 
        return true; 
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I use

```
if(checkblacklist($stringcomment)) {

}
```

Can you help me to check if something wrong because it does not work

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Your parameter is `$commnetct` and in your check you are using `$commnetc`.

Comment: You also don't need `break` after the `return` as it will never get there.

Comment: @NigelRen haha I see. thank you :D

Comment: What's wrong with `mail.ru`?))))

Comment: if you got the  right answer then mark it  as solution . It will help others .

Comment: @u_mulder My mail often got spammer from this address :D

Answer (score 2):

You did not passed parameters in your function

**Follow this code**

```
$blacklist = array("fuck","shit","pussy", "mail.ru","viagra pill", "bitcoin", "конце", "pharmacy", "bad credit","casinos");
function checkblacklist($commnetct,$blacklist) {
    foreach ($blacklist as $word) {
        if (strpos($commnetct, $word) !== FALSE) {
            return true;

        }
    }

    return false;
}

$stringcomment = "shit";
if(checkblacklist($stringcomment,$blacklist)) {
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```